# Upload file in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

By this code i am not able to upload my file in UserImage Folder also getting path  in database after upload my site on Local host On IIS before that it's works.
When i am press submit button Error Will Occured is -

> Access to the path
>   'C:\Users\PEERBITS\Desktop\ClientProj\ClientProj\UserImages\Lighthouse.jpg'
>   is denied.

Here is the code :

```
if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName);
    var path = Server.MapPath("~/UserImages/") + filename;
    uploadFile.SaveAs(path);
    ins.image_path = "~/UserImages/" + filename;
}
```

Comment: Try saving the file to a different location and access it, check whether you are getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Please check 'UserImages' folder's poperties.
Please remove **read-only** attribute of this folder.